# Create an empty chart for user to input data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

What is the best way to create an empty chart (like a spreadsheet) so that the user can fill the cells with some data (strings, numbers)? The number of rows and columns is not known, it's determined at runtime. The data given by the user should then be easily loaded to, say, 2D array. Is using DataGrid a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check

- [RadSpreadSheet](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/spreadsheet.aspx)
- [Infragistic WPF SpreadSheet](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/spreadsheet)
- [DevExpress Spreadsheet](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/spreadsheet/)
- [SynFunction Spreadsheet](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/spreadsheet)

These are third party control and **not free**.

This one is [open source control](http://simplespreadsheet.codeplex.com/).

Creating your own is of course lots of work and you may want to refer to these for a starter.

If you want to make a simple editable DataGrid follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx) link.

Also look at [IEditableCollectionView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/20/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-ieditablecollectionview.aspx)

> IEditableCollectionView is a new collection view that you can use to supports adding and removing new items, as well as editing items in a transactional way.  It is implemented by ListCollectionView (the default view for ObservableCollection) and BindingListCollectionView (the default view for DataTable).  I will go through an example to further describe it and summarize afterwards.

Comment: So I can't use the DataGrid or any other control to edit the cells?

Comment: Yes, you can use `DataGrid`'s `DataGridTextColumn` or `DataGridTemplateColumn` if you want to make your cells editable. But it won't have myriads of other functions that  **Excel** has.

Comment: I just want to allow the user to enter the numbers and press one button. That's it. But I don't really know how to create an empty chart with specified number of rows and columns that would allow the user to enter some numbers in those cells. Maybe you could help me in some way?